# Joda Time - inconsistent result

Tags: jodatime

I ran a quick test on `daysBetween` function in Joda-Time library and I am getting inconsistent result. Does anyone else have the same problem?

Below is the code I use for testing.

```java
public static int elapsedDaysJoda() {
    DateTime dt1 = new DateTime(new Date());        
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(2011, 0, 1); 
    DateTime dt2 = new DateTime(cal.getTime());
    Days days = Days.daysBetween(dt2, dt1);
    return days.getDays();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    for(int i=0; i < 10; i++) {
        System.out.println(elapsedDaysJoda());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, and main problem: you are asking Java for the "current datetime" twice, in `new Date()` and in `Calendar.getInstance()`, and you cannot be sure that this two calls will return exactly the same instant or if they can differ in a few milliseconds.

Besides, because  you are using `DateTime` instead of `LocalDate`,  that difference of a few milliseconds can alter the calculation of the elapsed days. If you are (conceptually) dealing with difference between days and you do not care about times (h:m:s.sss) perhaps you should better use `LocalDate`.

The first problem could be solved by asking for Java current datime only once:

```java
public static int elapsedDaysJoda() {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    DateTime dt1 = new DateTime(cal);
    cal.set(2011, 0, 1); 
    DateTime dt2 = new DateTime(cal.getTime());
    Days days = Days.daysBetween(dt2, dt1);
    return days.getDays();
}
```

In addition (or alternatively; this also fixes the inconsistent results), you could use `LocalDate` instead of `DateTime`.

Comment: Thank you for your clear explanation. LocalDate is what I needed.