# Joda-Time and Android system time

Tags: android, jodatime, android-date

Currently Joda DateTime can get the current Android system time, but is it possible to get the DateTime when say the Android system date or timezone has changed?

I have tried this after the Date/Timezone has changed but it does not work:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.now();
DateTime dt = new DateTime();
```

When I use the Calendar it works fine:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.getTime()  //Returns the correct changed Android Date and Time
```

Comment: The following link (http://stackoverflow.com/a/8713654/1012381) suggests using LocalDate instead of DateTime.

Comment: @JScoobyCed Thanks for the link, just had a look and tried the code, it works great. Can you put this up as the answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8711244/joda-time-inconsistent-result/8713654#8713654) post, you can get the Calendar time first:

```
public static int elapsedDaysJoda() {
  Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
  DateTime dt1 = new DateTime(cal);
  cal.set(2011, 0, 1); 
  DateTime dt2 = new DateTime(cal.getTime());
  Days days = Days.daysBetween(dt2, dt1);
 return days.getDays();
}
```